# PHP regex replace based on \v character (vertical tab)

Tags: php, regex

I have a character string like (ascii codes):

```
32,13,7,11,11, 
"string1,blah;like: this...", 10,10, 32,32,32,32, 138,138, 32,32,32,32, 13,7, 11,11, 
"string2/lorem/example-text...", 10,10, 32,32,32,32,32, 143,143,143,143,143
```

So the sequence is:

1. any characters, followed by my search string, followed by any
   characters
2. 11,11
3. the string I want to replace
4. any non-printable characters

If the block contains `string1` then I need to replace the next string with something else. The second string always starts directly after the 11,11.
I'm using PHP.

I thought something like this, but I am not getting the correct result:

```
$updated = preg_replace("/(.*string1.*?\\v+)([[:print:]]+)([[:ascii:]]*)/mi", "$1"."new string"."$3", $orig);
```

This puts "new string" between the 10,10 and the 138,138 (and replaces the 32's).
Also tried \xb instead of \v.

Normally I test with regex101, but not sure how to do that with non-printable characters. Any suggestions from regex guru's?

**Edit**: the expected output is the sequence:

```
32,13,7,11,11, 
"string1,blah;like: this...", 10,10, 32,32,32,32, 138,138, 32,32,32,32, 13,7, 11,11, 
"new string", 10,10, 32,32,32,32,32, 143,143,143,143,143
```

**Edit**: sorry for the confusion regarding the ascii codes.
Here's a complete example:

```
<?php 

$s  = chr(32).chr(32).chr(7).chr(11).chr(11);
$s .= "string1,blah;like: this...". chr(10).chr(10).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(138).chr(138);
$s .= chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(13).chr(7).chr(11).chr(11);
$s .= "string2/lorem/example-text...". chr(10).chr(10).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(143).chr(143).chr(143);

$result = preg_replace('/(.*string1.*?\v+)([[:print:]]+)([[:ascii:]]*)/mi', "$1"."new string"."$3", $s);
echo "\n------------------------\n";
echo $result;
echo "\n------------------------\n";
```

The text `string2/lorem/example-text...` should be replaced by `new string`.

Comment: If you want to match a linebreak, use `\R`.

Comment: linebreak is 10 right? I believe 11 is vertical tab.

Comment: Linebreak is either CR, or LF or CRLF, and if you use `/u` it should even find more line breaks.

Comment: Yes, so 10 or 13, right? The string I need to replace starts after 2x 11. That should be \v or \x11 but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Try [`(\bstring1\b.*)\R+([[:print:]]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/kX0lN7/4).

Comment: \x11 is 17 decimal (DC1), \x0b is 11 decimal (VT).

Comment: `\v` is a character class shorthand that matches any vertical whitespace character, including vertical tab.  Try using single quotes around the regex (always a good idea) and use only one backslash: `\v+`.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/f9R4Vu.

Comment: Or, you could use the proper form of `\x0b`. Not sure that `\xb` would be promoted to `\x0b` by some engines. Perl does.

Comment: @ sln: you're right, I got my hex and dec mixed up. @ wiktor: does not work (and you don't capture the \R+ ?). @ alan: thx, did so and same result (puts new string after the LF's after first string and before the 138's.

Comment: As for `\R`, it matches the same as `\v`, `\xb`, and many more, see http://ideone.com/jgbbtU. Why do you need to capture `\R+`? It does not matter since I added `\n` in the replacement. Surely the `\R+` can be moved to the capturing group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the examples, to make sure: the codes I listed are decimal ascii codes, e.g. 32 for space and 10,10 for 2x LF. Sorry if that caused confusion!

Comment: I will have to ask for 1) exact input you have (as a string literal), 2) expected output.

Comment: So many comments, yet the input is not clear.

Comment: What would happen if you actually put a VT in your source example ? I just did it on one of my posts in a code section and it works fine. Put one in the proper place, or tell me where you want it and I'll put it there for you.

Comment: thanks for everyone's comment. I have added complete code example of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a combination of things:

1. /mis was needed (instead of /mi)
2. \x0b was needed (instead of \v)

Complete working example:

```
<?php 

$s  = chr(32).chr(32).chr(7).chr(11).chr(11);
$s .= "string1,blah;like: this...". chr(10).chr(10).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(138).chr(138);
$s .= chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(13).chr(7).chr(11).chr(11);
$s .= "string2/lorem/example-text...". chr(10).chr(10).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(143).chr(143).chr(143);

$result = preg_replace('/(.*string1.*?\x0b+)([[:print:]]+)/mis', "$1"."new string", $s);
echo "\n------------------------\n";
echo $result;
echo "\n------------------------\n";
```

Thanks for everyone's suggestions. It put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

My php-cli halted every time `preg_match` has reached `char(138)` and I don't know why.

I will throw my hat on this RegEx (note: `\v` matches a new-line | no flags are set):

```
"[^"]*"[^\x0b]+\v{2}"\K[^"]*
```

PHP code:

```
$source = chr(32).chr(13).chr(7).chr(11).chr(11)."\"string1,blah;like: this...\"".chr(10).
chr(10).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(138).chr(138).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).
chr(13).chr(7).chr(11).chr(11)."\"string2/lorem/example-text...\"".chr(10).chr(10).chr(32).
chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(32).chr(143).chr(143).chr(143).chr(143).chr(143);


echo preg_replace('~"[^"]*"[^\x0b]+\v{2}"\K[^"]*~', "new string", $source);
```

Beautiful output:

```
"string1,blah;like: this..."

    ��    
"new string"

     �����
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/nEuAZ)

Comment: thanks revo. Your example has hard coded quotes in the strings. That is not the case. It turned out it was the combination of /mis and \x0b that resulted in a working solution, see my answer.